# El subproceso de Python agrega comillas dobles al último argumento

Tags: python

Parece que python subprocess.run agrega una comilla doble en el último argumento:

```
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> args = ['cmd', '/c', 'echo', 'hello']
>>> result = subprocess.run(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> result.stdout
b'hello"\r\n'
>>> stdout = str(result.stdout, "utf-8").strip()
>>> stdout
'hello"'
```

Estoy usando Windows 20H2 19042.928.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal arriba?

Answer (score 1):

Tus argumentos ya se ejecutan la terminal (según su sistema operativo) cuando usa subprocess.run(). Asi que no necesita el cmd arg. Todo lo que debe necesitar es:

```
import subprocess
 
args = ['echo', 'hello']
result = subprocess.run(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out = str(result.stdout, 'utf-8').strip()

print(out)
```